# Can't execute page objects pattern with WebdriverIO and Mocha

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am trying to use Page Object Pattern in my tests. I really struggle with many problem e.g. using Mocha I shouldn't use "eventually" when doing assertions but my tests fail without it. Am I doing something wrong? When I'm doing any console logs I get the info that my promise is {state: pending}

This is my first test: test1.spec.js:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import cartPage from '../pageobjects/cart.page';
import regeneratorRuntime from "regenerator-runtime";

const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
const { expect } = chai;
const { assert } = chai;

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();


describe('Test1 - All elements exist on the Cart Page', function () {
  before(function () {
    cartPage.open();
  });

  it('should validate if the Add button exists', function (done) {
    expect(cartPage.addButtonText.getText()).eventually.equal('Add').notify(done);
  });

  it('should validate if the Remove button exists', function (done) {
         expect(cartPage.removeButtonText.getText()).eventually.equal('Remove').notify(done);
  });
});
```

My cart.page.js looks this:

```
import Page from './page';

class CartPage extends Page {

  get addButtonText() { return browser.element('.button'); }
  // getAddTextButton() { return this.addButtonText.getText(); }

  get removeButtonText() { return browser.element('.remove_button'); }

  open() {
    super.open('/shopping-cart');
    browser.pause(5000);
  }
}

export default new CartPage();
```

I'm trying to write the second test:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import cartPage from '../pageobjects/cart.page';
import regeneratorRuntime from "regenerator-runtime";

const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
const { expect } = chai;
const { assert } = chai;

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();


describe('Test2 - All elements are clickable on the Cart Page', function () {
  before(function () {
    cartPage.open();
  });

  it('should validate if the Add button is clickable', function (done) {
cartPage.addButtonText.click();
```

I can't see the button is clicked. I get {status: pending} when trying to console.log. I can't set any values into the text field. I am running my tests with wdio, trying to use sync: true, false or commented it out but I can't see any difference

I am not sure if my approach is OK. I have tried many repos with Page Object Pattern but I failed each time

Comment: Can you show us wdio config file. Aslo what version of webdriver-io are you using?